# On an e-commerce site, how do you attribute a sale to PPC if a visitor comes from PPC but then returns to buy through another medium?

Tags: google, ecommerce, google-ads, conversions, ppc

Can we use cookies and if so how do we install this? What software could track this kind of conversion scenario?

Comment: Define what PPC is please.

Comment: It stands for Pay Per Click.

Comment: You could set a cookie based on the information that the PPC source gives you and then look for that cookie later. You'll need to give more information on your PPC system to get more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using Google Analytics , although it tracks the sale to last click , it greatly provides ability for multichannel funnel, that you can use to understand sequence of different traffic source yielding ultimate transaction.